# Java SimpleDateFormat.getTimeZone().getID() returns Asia/Jerusalem instead of Asia/Kolkata

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, date-format, zoneddatetime

`SimpleDateFormat's getTimeZone().getID()` method returns Asia/Jerusalem instead of Asia/Kolkata for the date with format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`. Actually in my development machine it returns Asia/Kolkata as expected. But in some other machine(production environment) it returns Asia/Jerusalem instead of Asia/Kolkata. Any idea what causes this and how to resolve it. Source code is given below:

```
String input = "Mon Jun 12 13:29:47 IST 2017";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");          
sdf.parse(input);
TimeZone timeZone = sdf.getTimeZone();
System.out.println(timeZone.getID());
```

Comment: Timezone abbreviations such as IST, EST, etc... are not unique. IST stands for both Israel Standard Time and India Standard Time. You should use a different method to represent the timezone in your timestamp.

Comment: It’s a well known problem with three and four letter time zone abbreviations. A third interpretation of IST is Irish Standard Time (Europe/Dublin).

Comment: Where can I find the list of time zone ids for the given time zone abbreviation. For example for the abbreviation IST the  time zone ids are Asia/Jerusalem, Asia/Kolkata, Europe/Dublin.

Comment: It was a good idea to post the last comment as [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811282/java-how-to-get-list-of-time-zone-id-s-for-the-given-time-zone-abbreviation). Let’s continue there.

Answer (score 3):

> Any idea what causes this…

It’s a well known problem with three and four letter time zone abbreviations. A third interpretation of IST is Irish Standard Time (Europe/Dublin). I don’t know exactly what causes one JVM to prefer one interpretation over another. In at least one case I have seen it prefer its default time zone setting over other interpretations. So if your development machine has an Asia/Kolkata time zone setting and your production machine hasn’t, this would probably be the explanation. However, I would not rely on this as a sure fact, and also I would want to write code robust enough to run on computers and JVMs with different time zone settings.

> …and how to resolve it.

Ideal solution: Avoid getting a date-time string with a three or four letter time zone abbreviation in it. Prefer a zone offset from UTC and/or a time zone name in the form continent/city. I acknowledge that this is not always possible.

Given your input string, since `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` are outdated and the modern Java date and time API is much more programmer friendly, and you have also tagged your question with the `ZonedDateTime` class, a part of the modern API, let’s take the modern solution first:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Collections.singleton(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")))
            .appendPattern(" uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
    System.out.println(dateTime.getZone());
```

It prints:

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

The second argument I pass to `appendZoneText()` is a set of preferred time zones. In [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneText-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Set-) it says “The matched preferred zone id will be used if the textural zone name being parsed is not unique.” This is what we are after here.

On my computer I was also able to solve the issue within your code using the outdated classes. I inserted the following line before parsing.

```
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

However, the documentation of the old classes is vaguer, so I would be less assured that this solution always works.

As an aside and no matter if you use the old or the modern classes, I recommend you always give explicit locale to your parsing. “Mon” and “Jun” are in English, so parsing will not work on a computer with a non-English locale setting unless you specify a locale. Let me guess, your date string isn’t in English because it comes from an English-speaking locale, but just because English is the universal language in computing. If so, I consider `Locale.ROOT` appropriate. I am already using it in my code. To use it in yours, add it as argument to the constructor:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
```

`Locale.ENGLISH` works to, as do other English-speaking locales.

Comment: I always thought that IST was Irish Standard Time, but using a `DateTimeFormatter` with `z  zzzz` pattern gives "IST  Irish **Summer** Time" in the summer and ["GMT  Greenwich Mean Time" in the winter](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/ireland/dublin). But I also found that ["Irish **Standard** Time"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-ireland) name is [used for the summer time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Ireland) as well. So, both names are valid? We really need a standard (ISO/RFC/whatever) for this...

Comment: @Hugo I couldn’t help laughing, I hope you forgive. In a number of answers and comments I have quoted [List of time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) for “Irish Standard Time”, though “Summer Time” clearly makes more sense given the usage. Ireland does use summer time (DST) and a standard time in winter, so this only makes the ambiguity even worse and goes to underline the point you and I are both making: the three letter abbreviations are ambiguous and non-standard and should be avoided.

Comment: I wonder why they call DST as "standard". Anyway, as both names are used, maybe none is wrong (although this is very confusing). And don't worry, I also laughed when found this. Until someone standardizes it, that's all we can do...

Comment: I think it’s too late to standardize, @Hugo. No one will give up their own long-standing interpretation at this point. “Avoid” is the way to go…